# wolframalpha bug calculating dice probability?

Tags: probability, dice, wolframalpha

I believe these questions should yield the same answer:

(The question is "what are the odds of throwing at least two 1's with 3 dice")

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2C1+on+3+6-sided+dice
(solution: 15/216)
and
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=at+least+two+1+on+3+6-sided+dice
(solution: 16/216)

It seems the first does not seem take into account 1,1,1 as solution. Perhaps it interprets the question as exactly two ones. But when showing the example roll on the bottom and pressing reroll, it does show up as a solution. This seems like a bug.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

**---- UPDATE ----**

So the bug boils down to:

When asking WolframAlpha the question:
"What are the odds of rolling *exactly* two 1's (and no more) with 5 dice?" (https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2C1+on+3+6-sided+dice)

The solution: 15/216 is correct, but the example box below shows 1,1,1 as possible result (press reroll a couple of times). This is especially unclear when you throw 5 dice and seeing 1,1,1,4,1 as valid result. It's very unclear if it interprets as *exactly* 1,1 or *at least* 1,1.

As @paxdiablo pointed out, Wolfram Alpha answers https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=exactly+two+1+on+3+6-sided+dice with the same probability, but without the bug (1,1,1 does not show up as valid answer).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that it *is* interpreting `1,1 on 3 6-sided dice` as *exactly* two 1's, not at least two. That discounts the `1,1,1` solution which explains the disparity:

```
 1    1   2-5  (5)
 1   2-5   1   (5)
2-5   1    1   (5)
              ----
              (15)

 1    1    1   (1)
              ----
              (16)
```

That gels with the precise probability given of 5/72 (15/216).

As to why it's putting forward `1,1,1` when you throw the dice, I would say that is a a bug if it's meant to agree with the input. That certainly appears to be the case as it always has the `1,1` at the start.

Interestingly enough, the `two 1 on 3 6-sided dice` query generates the same probability but, after trying 50 dice rolls, the `1,1,1` combo never appeared. Perhaps the natural language processing is different between the two different areas.

---

As an aside, I have submitted feedback to Wolfram Alpha to see what they say about it. If they ever get back to me, I'll post the response here.

*Update 1:* Standard form letter response has been received, so hopefully a further response will come shortly:

> We appreciate your feedback regarding Wolfram|Alpha. The issue you reported has been passed along to our development team for review. Thank you for helping us improve Wolfram|Alpha.

Comment: Yes, I mention this in the question. I will remove the 'not sure why' part, since this is a logical reason.

Comment: Nice find with the exactly two 1 on 3 6-sided dice query! There all seems to be locked into place and correct, and the case I describe triggers a sort of limbo state.